# What is E_YATINTE.exe?

Tags: windows, security

This program E_YATINTE.exe starts when windows runs. What is this program?

Description of this exe is EPSON Status Monitor 3.

It can be a virus or malware?

Comment: Where is the file located?  If you have an Epson printer, then it belongs to your printer, which means it is not malware.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a legit part of the Epson software: http://systemexplorer.net/file-database/file/e_yatinte-exe/31622599, apparently associated with the print spooler.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Epson inkjet printer that I use on my home network, and see the same type of processes actively running.  I am rather confident that it is harmless.

Remember that you can typically gain some peace-of-mind by doing a quick file scan with [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).  Additionally, you can potentially upload a copy of the worrisome file to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) to have it analyzed.